# T-test for "discrete" variable

Tags: t-test, percentage

In my dataset, I have 2 columns. Both of them are a percentage. However, they only take the following values : (0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100).
I would like to know if I could do a t-test on those 2 columns. I have more than 300 rows in my dataset.

Comment: Thanks to the size of the samples and the "short tailed" distributions, a t test is an option. But maybe it is easier to use a distribution-free test (e.g. Wilcoxon test or a permutation t test) to avoid boring discussions like "your data are not normal, so the t test is wrong". Make sure to pick a test that fits to the samples being paired or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !I've seen that using a non parametric tests such as Wilcoxon test requires a huge size of dataset. So that's why I was wondering if I could do something like a t-test or not.

Comment: If n=4 is huge, you are right. Otherwise not ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks to the size of the samples and the "short tailed"
>   distributions, a t test is an option. But maybe it is easier to use a
>   distribution-free test (e.g. Wilcoxon test or a permutation t test) to
>   avoid boring discussions like "your data are not normal, so the t test
>   is wrong". Make sure to pick a test that fits to the samples being
>   paired or not.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @MichaelM as a community wiki answer because it is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.